# Object Identity as hash key but for derived classes

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I have a scenario where some legacy code is using an object of type "Base" as a key in a dictionary.

I have a wrapper class that does some work in addition to the "Base" object, called it "BaseAggregate". It is not inheriting base, it is implementing a common interface but dispatching most of the work to "Base".

What is happening is that some code path is adding the object "Base" as the key to a dictionary. I can't change this code, I can however change my Equals and GetHashCode to use the same object as an equality.

```
class BaseAggregate : IBase
{
     private readonly IBase foo = new Base();
}
```

And people are putting the Base object as a key.

```
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is BaseAggregate)
        {
            return base.Equals(obj);
        }

        if (obj is Base)
        {
            return this.foo.Equals(obj);
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Is this a good implementation? What should my GetHashCode be?

Comment: Does `BaseAggregate` expose a method or property that returns `foo`? If so, the aggregate and the inner `foo` would be considered equal in the dictionary.

Comment: So what's your actual goal? `I can however change my Equals and GetHashCode to use the same object as an equality.` leads me to believing that you want to prevent your object from being added to a dictionary.